# How to static typing a list of gmpy2.mpq in Cython?

Tags: cython

I implementented a Gauss estimation function based on gmpy2.mpq. After profiling, it is proved to be the bottleneck of my program. I tried Cython to optimize it.

Cython is fantastic and the speed has already increased about two times, but I'm trying to make it faster by static typing.

There are two problems when I tring to do this:

1. gmpy2.mpq is a function instead of a type. How to static typing it?
2. how to static typing a list of a given type?

It would be great if there are some faster alternative to list.

I have attached the code just FYI.

```
def gauss_estimate(a, b):
    """Gauss estimation for integers

    :param a:a n*m 2d sequence of integers, where n>=m
    :param b:an n-length 1d sequence of integers
    :returns: a m-length 1d sequence of mpq that a@x=b, gmpy2.mpq is a fast
        implementing of fraction
    :raises: a SingularError if the rank of a is smaller than m
    :raises: a NoSolutionError if the rank of a is larger than m
    """
    cdef int n, m, i, j
    cdef list aa, bb
    if isinstance(a, ndarray):
        a = a.tolist()
    if isinstance(b, ndarray):
        b = b.tolist()
    aa = [[mpq(aii) for aii in ai] for ai in a]
    n = len(aa)
    m = len(aa[0])
    if n < m:
        raise ValueError('Wrong shape of a')
    for ai in aa:
        if len(ai) != m:
            raise ValueError('Wrong shape of ai')
    bb = [mpq(bi) for bi in b]
    if len(bb) != n:
        raise ValueError('Wrong shape of b')
    for i in range(m):
        if aa[i][i] == 0:
            for j in range(i, n):
                if aa[j][i] != 0:
                    aa[i], aa[j] = aa[j], aa[i]
                    bb[i], bb[j] = bb[j], bb[i]
                    break
            else:
                raise SingularError('The rank of a is smaller than m')
        bb[i] /= aa[i][i]
        for j in reversed(range(i, m)):
            aa[i][j] /= aa[i][i]
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            bb[j] -= aa[j][i] * bb[i]
            for k in reversed(range(i, m)):
                aa[j][k] -= aa[j][i] * aa[i][k]
            assert aa[j][i] == 0
    for i in range(m, n):
        if bb[i] != 0:
            raise NoSolutionError('No solution found')
    for i in reversed(range(m)):
        for j in range(0, i):
            bb[j] -= bb[i] * aa[j][i]
    for i in range(m):
        assert aa[i][i] == 1
    return tuple(bb[:m])
```

Comment: I think the answer is "not easily". You could use numpy arrays with `dtype=object` but might even end up being slower than using lists. You could also consider trying to use the `gmp` C library directly, but that's hard.

Comment: Yes. I'll try writing a C module instead.